# Where can I find Implementation specific information about my C++ library?

Tags: c++, hash, clang, std

I would like to know which hash function I am using in my C++ program. The `std::hash` function is implementation-specific. From the [Documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash):

> The actual hash functions are implementation-dependent and are not required to fulfill any other quality criteria except those specified above. [...]

I think I can find the version of the std lib that I am using by running `strings /path/to/libstdc++.so.6 | grep LIBCXX`. My program is linking against `libstdc++.so.6`. Is this correct?

The output is

```
...
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

If I interpret this correctly, I am using GNU C++ std lib version 3.4.28 (please correct me if I am wrong).

Where can I now look up which hash function this lib is using?

Note: Building with clang 10.0.0.

Comment: Find the source code for the library. Look it up in the source. That's what I'd do.

Comment: Have to admit that the source code did not really help on this one. See https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/78d6a7767ed57b50122a161b91f59f19c9bd0d19/include/functional#L2963

Comment: Why are you looking at llvm libcxx code when your question says you are using GNUs libstdc++?

Comment: Fair enough. So I would think that the GNU version is this one? https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/e6f323372efa29091cf052a276c15b9e6ebc00ae/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/functional#L1096 Still not super helpful